# IOS 6 Splitview with Navigation controller

Tags: ios6

hope someone can help in IOS6.
I'm would like to create a master / details with out default navigation bar from IOS.
I fount coconutkit had such feature but i'm try to use standard objective-c framework such as coco
any one can help.

Comment: Have you tried using the Xcode master-detail template and removing the navigation controllers that you don't want?

Comment: Thank you Abizem i found the below link can help       https://github.com/stack3/STSplitViewController